# Slicing 2D NumPy Array, removing first and last row and column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a 2D Numpy array of tile objects that serves as a map.  The outer ring is all "wall" values to make a closed border.  I want to make a copy of the inner values to iterate over without touching the outer rows and columns.  I'm trying:

```
inner_values = map.tiles[1:-1][1:-1]
```

to cut off the top and bottom rows and left and right columns.  My map is 100*70, and this keeps giving me an array of shape (96, 70) when I want (98, 68).  How can I use slices correctly to get my inner values?  Thanks!

Comment: Tbe second indexing is applied to the result of `map.tiles[1:-1]`.  The net slice is `[2:-2]`.  Not what you want.

Comment: As a side note, don't use `map` as variable name. This is a (very useful) python builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just about there...you can put all the indices inside the brackets to get what you want:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones([5, 5])
print(a)

# [[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]


a[1:-1, 1:-1] = 0
print(a)
# [[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
#  [1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
#  [1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Or given your dimensions:

```
a = np.ones([100,70])
a[1:-1, 1:-1].shape
# (98, 68)
```